# Need help determining if it's safe to decommission my Exchange 2007 VM

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2010

From all the documentation and guides I've been looking over I *think* it's safe for me to decommission my Exchange 2007 VM in favor of Exchange 2010.

- OAB has been moved to the new server.
- All mailboxes reside on the new server.
- No Public Folders need to be replicated.
- Exchange 2010 certificate is valid and setup correctly.
- OWA and ActiveSync work fine.
- I don't utilize an Edge Transport server.
- Exchange 2010 machine will route mail in all directions when the Exchange 2007 machine is turned off.

I'm just concerned that there's something I haven't paid attention to and am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've gone through Microsoft's checklist here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805032.aspx

Once that's done, take a backup of your environment and then uninstall Exchange through Programs and Features. If you've missed anything the uninstall wizard is smart enough to catch it (I've never seen it miss anything).